# Why is OnClickListener not working from Fragment used as a Alertdialog

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-alertdialog

I am using a fragment as a alertdialog. Inside the fragment I have a onclick listener, but it does not fire. What can I do?

**Fragment used as alertdialog code:**

```
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            View mview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_opskrift, null);
            mBuilder.setView((mview));
            AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

**Onclicklistener inside the fragment code:**

```
public class AddOpskrift extends Fragment  {

            private static  final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGES = 1;
            TextView filepath_name;

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_opskrift, container, false);

    filepath_name = (TextView) view.findViewById((R.id.billede_path)) ;


    Button soeg_billede = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.billede_button);
    soeg_billede.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGES);


        }

    });

    return view;
```

**Xaml:**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/billede_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_add_photo_white"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Tilføj billede "
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: "I am using a fragment as a alertdialog." – No, you're just using the same layout for both the `AlertDialog` and the `Fragment`. That does not mean that you're actually using the `Fragment` there.

Comment: Thanks for your informative comment. Please let me know how it is useful for me in this case.

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy/paste fumble. There should've been a question at the end of that. You don't have a `<fragment>` in the `fragment_add_opskrift` layout, do you? Also, if you're trying to get a `Dialog` as a `Fragment`, you should be using `DialogFragment`, instead of a plain `Fragment`.

Comment: No problem. I have tried to change it to DialogFragment, but the onclicklistener does not work still.

Comment: OK, if you're going with the `DialogFragment`, then you no longer need the `AlertDialog` at all. Since you're only returning a `View` for the `Fragment`, it will provide its own `Dialog`. What you need to do is kinda treat the `DialogFragment` as the `Dialog`. That is, get rid of the `AlertDialog` stuff, then `AddOpskrift dialog = new AddOpskrift(); dialog.show(get[Support]FragmentManager(), "AddOpskrift");`. `Support` is in brackets, 'cause I'm not sure if you're using the support library `Fragment`s or not. Also, the second argument there can be whatever `String` you want to use to tag it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though I still have problems with the onclicklistener since it wont fire.

Comment: We'd need to see your current `Fragment` code, the `show()` code, and possibly the complete layout XML.

Comment: The current fragment code is the same, just changed the extend to DialogFragment and the show() code is exactly the one you wrote.

Comment: Hmm, if you're sure, that sounds like a problem with your layout, then. Is there any visual feedback when you click the `Button`?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you at this point, other than we'd need to see a [mcve]. I just copied/pasted those things from the question, with the mentioned modifications, into a new project, and it works as expected for me. Are you absolutely certain that you're looking at the right `Button`? Have you tried logging inside `onClick()`, or even a `Toast`? It's not crashing, is it?

Comment: It is working now. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
Button soeg_billede = (Button) mview.findViewById(R.id.billede_button);
soeg_billede.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGES);
    }
});
```

should be written just before you show the dialog with `dialog.show();`.  
The change needed is `mview` instead of `view` for the `findViewById()`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. The first piece of code is a separate class opening the class mentioned in the second piece of code.

Comment: @MohammadSaad The listener must be set before the dialog is shown. This button belongs to the layout that is inflated in the dialog, so you must initialize it and its listener there. If you need to pass parameters like a context, pass them in the initialization of this class that creates the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in using fragment's layout with **AlertDialog** and actually using [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment)

**DialogFragment** is deprecated since **API 28**.

> This class was deprecated in API level 28.
>   Use the **Support Library DialogFragment** for consistent behavior across all devices and access to Lifecycle.